How does CodePush handle code deployment and what parts of my React Native app are hosted on Microsoft App Center?
How does CodePush handle code deployment and what parts of my React Native app are hosted on Microsoft App Center?
I'm a React Native developer and I'm considering using CodePush for my app updates. I understand that CodePush can push updates to users' devices without going through the app store approval process. However, I have some concerns and questions about how this process works, particularly regarding what parts of my app are hosted on Microsoft App Center.
Specifically:
Which parts of my React Native codebase are hosted on Microsoft's App Center servers when I use CodePush?
Are any sensitive parts of my app, such as native code or backend server code, uploaded to CodePush?
What exactly is bundled and uploaded during the CodePush release process?
How are updates applied to the user’s app and what security measures are in place to protect my app’s code?
Can updates be rolled back if something goes wrong, and how does this process work?
I want to ensure that my use of CodePush will not compromise the security of my app or its users' data. Any detailed explanation or best practices would be greatly appreciated.

you should consider about Visual Studio App Center retirement

CodePush is a service that is provided by Appcenter with other services like crash analytics, CI, testing, push notifications etc.
You can think that Google has Firebase for managing the above things and with some other services so similarly Microsoft has Appcenter.
You need to share your whole code repository to Appcenter via connecting Github or Bitbucket whatever you are using for hosting your codebase to be able to use their offered services.
Codepush only bundles the Javascript Code, not the native side code.
You can avoid your sensitive info (e.g. API keys) by assigning through environmental variables.
